# Increment file name in C

Tags: c, file-handling

I wish to increment the file name as below, and output them as files themselves. So there will be a total of 1000 files in my file directory.

**File1.txt**,
**File2.txt**,
…,
**File100.txt**,
**File101.txt**,
…,
**File1000.txt**.

How can I code it in C program?

```
char filename[1000][50];
FILE *fileunit[1000];
char temp[] = “file0.txt”;
char *fp;

for (i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
    fp = temp;
    fp += 4;
    *fp += 1;
    fp -= 4;
    *temp = *fp;
    strcpy(filename[i], temp);
    fileunit[i] = fopen(filename[i], “w”);
}
```

With this, I am able to output **File1.txt**, …, **File9.txt**. How can I improve my codes to output files until **File1000.txt**. Thank you!

Comment: Please see [help/on-topic].  We are happy to help but you should write some code first instead of asking us to do the work for you.

Comment: Have you tried a loop and `snprintf`?

Comment: You set `fp` equal to `temp`, then add 4 to `fp`, then subtract 4 from `fp`. At that point, `fp` and `temp` are equal again. So `*temp = *fp;` is no different from `*temp = *temp;` and does nothing.

Answer (score 3):

Probably you don't know the `snprintf` function, which does exactly what you want. I'll leave here an example, and you can find [here](https://linux.die.net/man/3/snprintf) the Posix documentation.

*You can be tempted by using `sprintf` and in this case it will work fine because you know exactly how large is your buffer. However, for more dynamic cases where the user does not know a priori which is the length of the final string, `snprintf` is the safe option, which gives you the chance to know if the string was truncated.*

```
#define STR_MAX_LEN 256
// Init to all zeros, so that you have 0 ended strings.
char filename[STR_MAX_LEN] = {0}; 

int ret;

for ( int i = 1; i <= N_FILES; i++)
{
    // -1 because we want to leave a "0" at the end. 
    ret = snprintf(filename, STR_MAX_LEN-1, "my_file_%d.txt", i);
    if( ret < 0) // Error handling
    else if( ret >= STR_MAX_LEN-1 ) // Truncated
}
```

Comment: `= {0}` is not necessary, `snprintf` takes care of the terminating 0. And (not that it really matters) `STR_MAX_LEN-1` should be `STR_MAX_LEN`.

Comment: I think it still is a good practice to take care of it, but good point!

Comment: Please check the return value of `snprintf()`

Comment: I disagree with the blanket warning against `sprintf`. It's just as safe or unsafe as `strcpy`; if you *know* the length of your buffer, and you *know* the maximum length of your output, there is nothing wrong with using `sprintf` as the length check would merely duplicate what you already know.

Comment: @Jabberwocky No, not when the resulting string would be too long. `snprintf()` does not add a `'\0'` in this case.

Comment: @DevSolar even Posix documentation gives a word of warning against it "Because sprintf() and vsprintf() assume an arbitrarily long string, callers must be careful not to overflow the actual space; this is often impossible to assure. Note that the length of the strings produced is locale-dependent and difficult to predict. Use snprintf()"

Comment: @Fra93 *this is often impossible to assure* does not means that it is not possible, and in this case, it is possible.

Comment: @12431234123412341234123, wrong, `snprintf` __always__ puts a null terminator. `snprintf` is not like `strncpy` in this regard.

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteYunès I agree with you, but what if I had used `sprintf` and someone copies the code, changes it to work on a random string from a user which could exceed the MAX_STRLEN? I know that it is the programmer's fault, but why risk it? I just put an advice. **I add a better warning nevertheless**

Comment: @Jabberwocky: According to the C Standard, `snprintf` does set a null terminator at the end of the array whose size is given as the second argument, but broken implementations are numerous on legacy platforms: as implicitly documented on the [Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/snprintf-snprintf-snprintf-l-snwprintf-snwprintf-l?view=msvc-170) their implementation of `snprintf` failed to set a null terminator in case of truncation up to and including VS 2015.

Comment: @Fra93 We have `"my_file_%d.txt", i`, with `i` being `< N_FILES`, so we know *exactly* how long the target string may be, and there is no locale dependecy involved.

Comment: @DevSolar yes, I changed the warning!

Comment: STR_MAX_LEN-1` --> off-by 1 in 2 places.   Use  `STR_MAX_LEN`.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica * Thus, a return value of size or more means that the output was truncated.*

Comment: @Fra93 True , yet `snprintf(filename, STR_MAX_LEN-1, "my_file_%d.txt", i)` should not have the `- 1` either.  Better and easier to code, review and maintain as `snprintf(filename, sizeof filename, "my_file_%d.txt", i);`

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica  This is to ensure that the last byte is a 0. We know that snprintf puts a zero at the end, but reading the comments it seems that some implementations fail to do so.

Comment: I do not ascribe to coding to old broken implementations and instead encourage coding to the C standard.

Comment: If you find your implementation breaks the standard, don't for a *second* try to patch your way around it -- *find another implementation*.